# App does not start on Torch

Tags: blackberry

I have developed a couple of Blackberry applications for the 9000 and the 9700. They work well on these platforms but with the Torch (9800) my application won't start.

I get an error message that `no bbi auth token request engine available`. When we click the white screen I get "no stack trace" message..

So I really dont know what to do.  Do I have to change my app's screen resolution or anything else?

Comment: Which OS version do you have on the 9000 and 9700? It could be a difference between OS5 and OS6

Answer (score 0):

The Torch only runs on the recently released OS 6.  I suggest you check your exact OS 6 version as I found that my app would only show a blank white screen on the earliest OS 6 releases.  The problem was fixed in OS release 6.0.0.246 and above (i.e. my app started working again once I upgraded to that OS release).

Remember to test all the new features in OS 6 as you are likely to find bugs in your application.  For example, touch and hold brings up a new context menu with images - if you don't add images to your menus then they use the ugly defaults.  I also found with my app that doing this repeatedly would result in lots of duplicate copies of my menu options appearing in the list.  I hadn't got as far as investigating if this is a bug in my code or OS 6, but I know the problem doesn't occur on 4.5, 4.7 or 5.0 OS versions.

I believe OS 6 is also available for the 9700 now, but I haven't tested that yet.